# How should I organize my Android uiautomator testing case?

Tags: android, user-interface, functional-testing

I am trying to automate the majority of my Android app's UI testing cases using the newly release android Testing Framework, uiautomator.

All together there are 17 testing cases or so. And I want to know should I organize my testing code. Or are there any best practice to do it ?

uiautomator is using Junit 3. But it seems that you can only run one class at a time, eg:

```
    adb shell uiautomator runtest myApp-ui-testing.jar -c com.myAndroidApp.test.ui.trial.SearchNearbyUITesting
```

Should I dump all my testing cases in one class or to put them in different classes and run the above command many times using a shell script?

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated :D

Answer (score 1):

```
uiautomator runtest myApp-ui-testing.jar -c com.myAndroidApp.test.ui.trial.SearchNearbyUITesting -c com.myAndroidApp.test.ui.trial.SearchNearbyUITesting2 -c com.myAndroidApp.test.ui.trial.SearchNearbyUITesting3
```

Using this command you can add as many classes as you want and run it.

It's working for me.